# Picture in picture mode in ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have created a WhatsApp like app in ionic which allows the user to chat, video call and share files. I would like to add the feature where the user can minimize the video calling screen to a corner of the screen and do the regular chat. Like we can do in WhatsApp. My question is, is it possible to create a picture in picture mode in the ionic app? Any guidance would be of great help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 
[cordova-plugin-pip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-pip)

PS: I haven't personally used the plugin yet.